# How to record "stereo mix" with VLC?

Tags: sound, vlc, audio-recording

I would like to record a stereo mix (basically what I hear through the speakers connected to my sound card) from VLC. However, I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to do this.

Under the "video4linux" capture device, I see the following audio devices:

```
hw:0,0
hw:0,6
```

However, selecting either of those results in VLC trying to use my webcam (*not* what I want at all) in addition to the selected audio device.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Record stereo from what exactly?

Comment: @dobey: Basically record whatever my sound card is playing - whether that includes the soundtrack from a movie, music being played by Rhythmbox, or even sound effects from a game.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about VLC, but you should be able to record in `audacity`. You'll need to install the `pavucontrol` package, and set Audacity's recording device to the `loopback` device in the sound preferences, and the application you're trying to record from, to the `loopback` device for its output. You'll also need to record the audio into a stereo track in Audacity. This is of course an internal loopback system, and the audio won't be output to the speakers as well.

Comment: Sadly I really need to record in VLC.

Comment: If VLC is going through pulseaudio, then similar details will work.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use VLC.  i just figured out exactly how.  first off make sure your stereo mix is enabled (within your system's sound settings).  Then, in VLC, go to media, then open capture device.  select none for video, then select stereo mix for sound.  then press play and make sure to mute the sound on VLC or else you will have a reverbish loop with the original sound plus VLC playing the same sound with a delay.  then simply press record to begin recording.